# Ractive and arrays, data not being updated

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm learning how to use [ractive](http://www.ractivejs.org/) and can't solve a problem, the code is at the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4c8j/10/).

The gist of what I'm doing is counters for a queue (last object in array is current person):
1. A counter to display the queue number of the current person
2. A counter to display the size of the queue

A) works correctly but it is bloated with logic so I tried to convert it into a separate variable, as shown in B) but it doesn't update at all.

I put an observer in the code to watch when there is any change to the queue variable. I expect it to show an alert every time I click on "skip current person" or "delete current person" but the alert only shows up in the first time I load the page.

```
    ractive.observe({
      'queue.0.queueNo': alert('here')
    });
```

Comment: You're not changing their queueNo - the data is staying the same, with the whole object being moved from front to back

Comment: I should have made my variables more obvious, queueNo is the attribute of the element. I was referring to queueNum, that is a key defined in the data hash of the ractive object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make queueNum a function based on queue like this:

```
num: function(q) { return q[(q.length-1)].queueNo;}
```

and call it like so: `{{num(queue)}}`
now when queue or people gets updated reactive knows it has to update num to. You don't even have to call ractive.update().
For the observe also make it a function and it will work:

```
ractive.observe({
    'queue.0.queueNo': function(a,b) { alert('here');}
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works now! Do you know why I couldn't use my queueNum as I had in my example (set to read from the people array)? I'm just curios as queue updated correctly so I expected the same behavior from queueNum.

Comment: Don't know the exact inner workings of ractive, so don't know why it doesn't work. Just my own experience with ractive that it works like this.

Answer (score 6):

Wim's answer is a good one - `{{num(queue)}}` is an elegant solution.

The reason you can't use `queueNum` is that when you do

```js
queueNum = people[(people.length-1)].queueNo
```

the value of `queueNum` is set to *whatever the value of* `people[(people.length-1)].queueNo` is *at the time of the statement*. When the queue is altered, `queueNum` doesn't get re-evaluated. This isn't a Ractive thing so much as a JavaScript thing.

Another way of saying it is

```js
a = 1;
b = 2;
foo = a + b; // foo === 3

a = 3;
b = 4;
alert( foo ); // alerts '3' - foo is the same, even though a and b changed
```

This is actually the same reason that the `alert('here')` was only triggering when the page loaded - rather than telling Ractive to trigger the alert when the value changed by wrapping it in a function, as in the second code block of Wim's answer, the code was executed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rich, that made things very clear. I'm new to programming in general so the javascript explanation was helpful.